# Joomla K2 change "read more" link

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I'm using the K2 Component in Joomla to manage my articles and categories.

Now, I want to link the 'read more'-button to another article, but I don't find the option to change this link (default linked to the article itself). How could I change that?

Comment: why would you want to link it to another article? A read more is supposed to link you to the full text of the same article.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option in K2 to change this. Will the Read More buttons always link to the same article, or does this need to be configurable?

If it is always the same, you could likely create a K2 sub-template to do this.

Otherwise, you would likely need to create a custom plugin.